# How to resize a QImage or QML Image to fit parent container without breaking the Image's aspect ratio

Tags: image, qt, qml, qtquick2, qimage

**Scenario:**
I have an [Image](https://doc-snapshots.qt.io/qt5-dev/qml-qtquick-image.html) component in QML which contains a [QImage](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qimage.html) of varied aspect ratios.

**Code:**

```
Window {
  id: app_window
  visible: true

  Rectangle {
    id: my_image_view_container
    width: app_window.width
    height: app_window.height

    Image {
       id: my_image
       // changes at runtime based on the image my app selects
       source: "random/path/to/an/image.jpg"
       width: sourceSize.width
       height: sourceSize.height
       scale: Qt.KeepAspectRatio
    }
  }
}
```

**Question:**
How do I set the `width` & `height` of the `my_image_view_container` so as to fit `my_image` completely inside `my_image_view_container` without disturbing its aspect ratio?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You can use fillMode property.
Like this

```
fillMode: Image.PreserveAspectFit
```

Comment: Exxactly what I was looking for. I knew this property long time ago. Was missing to set this right. thanks a ton !